# Direction-splitting for SSP-RK schemes

Tags: pde, advection, operator-splitting

What are the implications of applying a direction-splitting within each stage of an SSP-RK scheme?

For instance, given a standard advective transport type equation:
$$
\partial_{t}Q + \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{u}Q) = 0
$$
it's popular to make use of an explicit SSP-RK style time-stepping scheme, such as the well-known SSP-RK2 method:
$$
Q^{(1)} = Q^{(n)} - \Delta t \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{u}Q^{(n)}) 
\\[1ex]
Q^{(2)} = \tfrac{1}{2}Q^{(n)} + \tfrac{1}{2}Q^{(1)} - \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{u}Q^{(1)})
\\[1ex]
Q^{n+1} = Q^{(2)}
$$
But if the flux terms  can only be evaluated via a direction-splitting:
$$
\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{u}Q) = \partial_{x}(uQ) + \partial_{y}(vQ)
$$
what are the implications of advancing each RK stage according to a simple direction split:
$$
Q^{(1a)} = Q^{n}
\\[1ex]
Q^{(1b)} = Q^{(1a)} - \Delta t \, \partial_{x}(uQ^{(1a)})
\\[1ex]
Q^{(1c)} = Q^{(1b)} - \Delta t \, \partial_{y}(vQ^{(1b)})
\\[2ex]
Q^{(2a)} = \tfrac{1}{2}Q^{n} + \tfrac{1}{2}Q^{(1c)}
\\[1ex]
Q^{(2b)} = Q^{(2a)} - \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t \, \partial_{y}(vQ^{(2a)})
\\[1ex]
Q^{(2c)} = Q^{(2b)} - \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t \, \partial_{x}(uQ^{(2b)})
\\[2ex]
Q^{n+1} = Q^{(2c)}
$$
Is the order of the method reduced? Does it loose its SSP property? Is it possible to combine such an approach with SSP-RK3 to get a third-order accurate method?

Comment: What is your reason for splitting?  Why not just compute each of the directional derivative approximations and then apply them simultaneously to update the solution?